# dual NIC port show only 1 ethernet interface on Dell M620

Tags: networking, dell, ethernet

I have a Dell M620 server with Intel(R) Ethernet 10G 2P X520-k bNDC
But when I installed Ubuntu 14.04.02, I could only see 1 interface in the system?
And why the capacity is only 1G/s? Should it 10G/s?

Did I configure something wrong? I talked to Dell people they said there is no problem with hardware, let me ask Ubuntu community.
Thanks a lot.

```
d@cluster:~$  sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for d: 
  *-network:0             
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82599 10 Gigabit Dual Port Backplane Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: em1
       version: 01
       serial: 5c:f9:dd:b9:48:dc
       size: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical fibre autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=ixgbe driverversion=3.19.1-k duplex=full firmware=0x800007f6 ip=10.200.0.20 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:36 memory:d8d00000-d8dfffff ioport:fcc0(size=32) memory:d8ff8000-d8ffbfff memory:d8000000-d807ffff memory:d5300000-d53fffff memory:d5400000-d54fffff
  *-network:1 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82599 10 Gigabit Dual Port Backplane Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
       logical name: em2
       version: 01
       serial: 5c:f9:dd:b9:48:de
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical fibre 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=ixgbe driverversion=3.19.1-k firmware=0x800007f6 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes
       resources: irq:34 memory:d8e00000-d8efffff ioport:fce0(size=32) memory:d8ffc000-d8ffffff memory:d8080000-d80fffff memory:d5500000-d55fffff memory:d5600000-d56fffff
  *-network:0 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82599 10 Gigabit Dual Port Backplane Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: p3p1
       version: 01
       serial: 5c:f9:dd:b9:48:e0
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical fibre 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=ixgbe driverversion=3.19.1-k duplex=full firmware=0x80000818 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes
       resources: irq:52 memory:d5000000-d50fffff ioport:dcc0(size=32) memory:d52f8000-d52fbfff memory:da000000-da07ffff memory:da100000-da1fffff memory:da200000-da2fffff
  *-network:1 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82599 10 Gigabit Dual Port Backplane Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.1
       logical name: p3p2
       version: 01
       serial: 5c:f9:dd:b9:48:e2
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical fibre 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=ixgbe driverversion=3.19.1-k firmware=0x80000818 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes
       resources: irq:48 memory:d5100000-d51fffff ioport:dce0(size=32) memory:d52fc000-d52fffff memory:da080000-da0fffff memory:da300000-da3fffff memory:da400000-da4fffff

d@cluster:~$ ifconfig 
em1       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 5c:f9:dd:b9:48:dc  
          inet addr:10.200.0.20  Bcast:10.200.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5ef9:ddff:feb9:48dc/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:178920 errors:0 dropped:3184 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:839 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:16633293 (16.6 MB)  TX bytes:100033 (100.0 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1184 (1.1 KB)  TX bytes:1184 (1.1 KB)

d@cluster:~$ uname -a
Linux cluster 3.16.0-30-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 15 17:43:14 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

i actually had the same issue as i was fixed on the old ethX naming scheme and trying with emX / ethX combinations

as you did, you get with "sudo lshw -C network" the network card details .. in my case

```
  *-network:0 DISABLED    
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
   logical name: p2p1
   version: 01
   serial: xxxxxxx
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress vpd bus_master 
   cap_list rom ethernet physical fibre
   configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=ixgbe 
   driverversion=3.19.1-k firmware=0x8000081f latency=0 link=no 
   multicast=yes
   resources: irq:48 memory:d9d00000-d9dfffff ioport:ecc0(size=32) 
   memory:d9ff8000-d9ffbfff memory:d9000000-d907ffff 
   memory:d5100000-d51fffff memory:d5200000-d52fffff
```

now using the "logical name" (for extension cards the pXpX scheme) in the lspci output, in /etc/network/interfaces will activate the network interface

I was running it fine in a fujitsu system, where the devices show as ethX and non defined network interfaces can be probed with the ethtool 
(sudo ethtool eth2)

so another way would be to change the naming back to ethX
(emX / pXpX is the new naming scheme)

```
  Edit /etc/default/grub and find these lines:
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

  Add biosdevname=0, just like this:
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="biosdevname=0"
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="biosdevname=0"

  Then run:
  sudo update-grub
  sudo reboot
```